# How to connect to oracle db from aws lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, pyspark, aws-lambda

I've below pyspark code trying to execute in aws Lambda functions, but its failing and throwing mentioned error:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    qry1DF = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(url=myjdbcUrl, dbtable="(select * from emp) qry1alias", driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").load()
qry1DF.write.format("csv").option("header", "true").save("s3://mybucket/test/Lambda_test_259")
```

error:
Unable to import module '`lambda_function`': No module named '`pyspark`'

Also I need to setup `ojdbc7.jar` to this to connect to oracle db, how can i resolve above error message and how to set the jar file to succesffully connect to db.

Thanks

Comment: You need to include the packages and jar in you lambda function correctly. Follow this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html